# How to add handles to spiral curve to warp a spiral Blender

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I want to make a warped spiral or helix.

I figured I would do this by creating a spiral or helix from the add-on add curve: extra objects and be able to manipulate the control points with a handle to create a warped shape but I can't figure out if there is a way to add handles to a spiral or helix.

any suggestions or alternative approaches to creating an oval spiral? [image]

Answer (score 4):

Change the curve type to *Bezier*:

[image: Bezier]

You will then have to change the handle type to *Aligned*:

[image: Align]

After this, *Recalculate* the curve "flow" (direction) to make the spiral smooth:

[image: Recalculate]

Doing it this way may give you too many points for your liking, however - you can get away with using fewer steps (points) when creating the base spiral. You can also change the generated curve type to *Bezier* and set the Handles to *Auto* all in one go (as opposed to all the steps above):

[image: CurveSettings]